# Why does using "or" in SQL (Snowflake) joins make queries much slower?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables:

**trips**, with columns user_id and bike_id

**experiment_exposures**, with columns subject_type and subject_id

`subject_type` can be `User` or `Bike` and the `subject_id` corresponds to either the `user_id` or `bike_id`.

The first two queries are both relatively fast, they take roughly the same time:

```
select count(*)
from trips
join experiment_exposures e1 on e1.subject_type = 'User' and e1.subject_id = trips.user_id
join experiment_exposures e2 on e2.subject_type = 'Bike' and e2.subject_id = trips.bike_id;
```

and

```
select count(*)
from trips
join (select * from experiment_exposures where subject_type = 'User') e1 on e1.subject_id = trips.user_id
join (select * from experiment_exposures where subject_type = 'Bike') e2 on e2.subject_id = trips.bike_id;
```

However, this query is at least 100 times slower:

```
select count(*)
from trips
join experiment_exposures e
  on (e.subject_type = 'User' and e.subject_id = trips.user_id)
  or (e.subject_type = 'Bike' and e.subject_id = trips.bike_id);
```

Why is there such a large difference? Aren't the first and third queries basically the same? Intuitively, I'd expect the third query to be faster because there's only 1 join.

Comment: Have you looked at the explain plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third query is different!  It returns additional *rows* when there is a match, rather than additional *columns*.

In your case, the `count()` won't even be the same.

Just as a small example:

```
user_id   bike_id
  1          1
  1          2

ee_id   subject_type  subject_id
  1        bike           1
  2        bike           2
  3        user           1
```

Your first two joins produce an intermediate table like this:

```
user_id   bike_id    ee_id_user    ee_id2_bike
  1          1          3              1
  1          2          3              2
```

The second returns:

```
user_id   bike_id    ee_id    subject_id
  1          1          3         user
  1          2          1         bike
  1          1          3         user
  1          2          2         bike
```

Hence the results are quite different.

Your question, though, is about performance.  That is related, but non-equality joins are often much less efficient than equi-joins.  This applies to `OR` and `IN` in the `ON` clause (as well as other inequalities) when there is no corresponding equality.

Comment: What Gordon said - OR in equi joins requires a very different implementation, which is in most systems much slower. You can often work around that with UNION ALL or UNION, but I admit it's subperfect.